# How to make a segue from SpriteKit GameScene to UIViewController programmatically in iOS 9 with Swift2

Tags: sprite-kit, segue, identifier, swift2, ios9

I need to make a segue from a GameScene to a UIViewController but i keep getting *Use of unresolved identifier "push"* although I did give it that identifier

In the GameSceneViewController I added

```
scene.viewController = self
```

and in my GameScene I added

```
var viewController: UIViewController?
```

and

```
func segue(){

    self.viewController.performSegueWithIdentifier(push, sender: viewController)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue identifiers are `String` objects, so you should call `performSegueWithIdentifier` with `"push"` instead of referencing it as a variable.

This code should work:

```
func segue(){

    self.viewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("push", sender: viewController)
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! I tried that before but I used AnyObject as the sender instead of viewController so it didn't work, my mistake, thanks!